# Showing a differential operator is positive semidefinite

Tags: differential-operators, sturm-liouville-theory

Let $R>\lambda>\chi$ be positive real constants and $\alpha$ be a real number. The following differential operator
\begin{multline}
\mathcal{L}g = -\frac{d}{d\xi}\left[(1-\xi^2)\frac{dg}{d\xi}\right] + 2R\xi(1-\xi^2)\frac{dg}{d\xi} + \left[\lambda - \alpha\chi-2\alpha R\left(3\xi^2-1\right)\right]g(\xi)
\\ = -e^{R\xi^2}\frac{d}{d\xi}\left[(1-\xi^2)e^{-R\xi^2}\frac{dg}{d\xi}\right] + \left[\lambda - \alpha\chi-2\alpha R\left(3\xi^2-1\right)\right]g(\xi)
\end{multline}
is self-adjoint on $L^2\left([-1,1],e^{-R\xi^2}\right)$, and thus has a nice set of orthogonal eigenfunctions. I'm trying to find the value of $\alpha$ for which the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathcal{L}$ is zero. Numeric analysis suggests that this is also the largest value of $\alpha$ for which all eigenvalues are nonnegative.

One thing I noticed that if you separate $\mathcal{L}$ into two operators, $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_\lambda - \alpha\mathcal{L}_\chi$, then $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$ is clearly positive definite. But I'm less sure of what to do with $\mathcal{L}_\chi$, as I can't assume $\alpha \ll 1$--numerical evidence suggests that the desired value of $\alpha$ is always larger than 1.

Another avenue is to expand in some basis functions. The even and odd orders of this equation are decoupled, and expanding in the even Legendre functions yields a nice infinite tridiagonal matrix. This is a good way to do the problem numerically, but I'm not sure how to analyze said matrix, as it's neither symmetric nor bounded. It might be symmetric in the basis defined by the eigenfunctions of $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$, but I can't get an analytic form for those either.

So is there a good way to analytically determine (or even just estimate) the value of $\alpha$ for which the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathcal{L}$ is zero in terms of $R$, $\lambda$, and $\chi$, or am I stuck with just solving this numerically?